# How would you build an AutoSPConfigurator (to be used when farm is installed)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, provider-hosted-app, autospinstaller

I would like to have a tool that is an equalent to AutoSPInstaller, but for configuring the most used out-of-the-box features.

It would do the following:

- Create sites
- Upload term set and configure navigation
- Create List and libraries
- Deploy webtemplates and WSP's
- Setting masterpages
- Adding webparts and pages

Question is: How would you go ahead and build this tool?

1. Like AutoSPInstaller (a GUI that creates a XML file, that acts as input to a powershell script)
2. A Winform using CSOM
3. Provided hosted app using CSOM, JSOM
4. SharePoint hosted app using JSOM
5. Powershell / CSOM mix like [this project](https://sharepointpowershell.codeplex.com/) which actually does a lot of the things I'm looking for

The disadvantage of number 1 is that it seems to be a bit limited what can be done using sharepoint online commands.

It might be that this tool already exist - if so please let me know!!!

Thanks for any hints or direction on how to implement this

Regards

Lars Erik